# "overwrite" argument default value set to "recursive"

Tags: r

In "file.copy" R function,
what mean "recursive" in "overwrite" argument default value ?

```
> args(file.copy)
function (from, to, overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE,  
    copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means `overwrite` will use the value of `recursive` by default. Since `recursive` is false by default, `overwrite` will be false if both are left unspecified. If you change `recursive` to true and leave `overwrite` unspecified, it will also become true. It's just telling you where the default value is coming from.

| call | overwrite | recursive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file.copy() | FALSE | FALSE |
| file.copy(recursive=TRUE) | TRUE | TRUE |
| file.copy(overwrite=TRUE) | TRUE | FALSE |
| file.copy(overwrite=FALSE, recursive=TRUE) | FALSE | TRUE |